# Running @Theory annotated test only once until passed

Tags: junit, annotations, theory, exit, datapoint

I have @Theroy class as:

```
@Datapoints data1, data 2 ..... data 10 and,

@Theory
testMethod (data1, data2, data3) {
 //do testing
 exit from testMethod once testing is passed
}
```

I want to pass the testing exactly once, but not to run all the possible cases of datapoints.

Apparantly, i just want to test once, and exit to another test once passed.

I am not wishing System.exit() ... because I am not exiting jvm, but only that @Theory test
 is to be exit.

```
Thanks
```

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean passed = false;

@Theory
public void testMethods(Object data){
    assumeTrue(!passed);

    // testing here

    passed = true;
}
```

Use Assume which will skip tests without reporting a failure.

Answer (score -1):

Didnot work for me, my case is :

```
boolean actual = false;
@Theory(nullsAccepted = false)
public void overlapIfFirstRangeEndsAfterSecondBegins(final Date start1,
        final Date end1, final Date start2, final Date end2) {
    // Assume ranges are valid
    Assume.assumeTrue(!actual);
    assumeThat(start1, before(end1));
    assumeThat(start2, before(end2));

    assumeThat(start1, onOrBefore(start2));
    assumeThat(end1,   onOrAfter(start2));

    actual = dateRangesOverlap(start1, end1, start2, end2);
    //this actual will be TRUE once when test is to be passed...then test must exit
}
```

Test case continued running....

And using assumeTrue made test case fail also.
thanks

Comment: The way assumeThat works is that each test case is run but potentially skipped. If you are taking 4 arguments to your theory and there are 10 or more datapoints, this is a very large number of possible combinations of values to be passed to the Theory. The assumeThat runs against each of them. I suggest that Theory is not the way to do this. You might want to consider Parameterized.

Comment: yea thanks...thats what i was thinking...after successing on all AssumeThat() conditions, and again successing in dateRangesOverlap()...that means first test is passed, right....now i wanted to exit from test and keep continue with another one...
... looks like theroy is playing bad role here....